# How can I map a selected field into domain properties with LINQ To Entity

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, sql-server-2012

I use C# And EF5 CodeFirst. Sql Server 2012 And VS2012

I have multiple domains in the form below in Entity Framework.

```
    public class Subscribe : BaseEntity
{

    public Subscribe()
    {

        this.SubscribeTariffHistories = new List<SubscribeTariffHistory>();
        this.SubscribeTotalHistories = new List<SubscribeTotalHistory>();

    }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool FirstCngDate { get; set; }

    public decimal AfterSaleDebit { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualDebit { get; set; } 
    public decimal AvrageFridayUsagePerMonth { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<SubscribeTariffHistory> SubscribeTariffHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubscribeTotalHistory> SubscribeTotalHistories { get; set; }

}
```

And

```
public class SubscribeTotalHistory : BaseEntity
{
    public SubscribeTotalHistory()
    {


    }
    public string FromDateTime { get; set; }
    public int SubscribeId { get; set; } 
    public int SubscribeTariefHistoryId { get; set; }
    public string ToDateTime { get; set; }
    public decimal? VeteranPercent { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscribe  Subscribe { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
    public class SubscribeTariffHistory : BaseEntity
{

    public SubscribeTariffHistory()
    {

        this.SubscribeTotalHistories = new List<SubscribeTotalHistory>();

    }
    public int BillingCalculateTypeId { get; set; } 
    public decimal FamilyCount { get; set; } 
    public string FromDateTime { get; set; } 
    public int SubscribeId { get; set; } 
    public string ToDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscribe  Subscribe { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubscribeTotalHistory> SubscribeTotalHistories { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
    public class BillingCalculateType : BaseEntity
{
    public BillingCalculateType()
    {
        this.SubscribeTariffHistories = new List<SubscribeTariffHistory>();
    }
    public string AdiTitle { get; set; } 
    public decimal Code { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 


    public virtual ICollection<SubscribeTariffHistory> SubscribeTariffHistories { get; set; }
}
```

And as I wrote the following command in My business in search method.

```
        public IQueryable<SubscribeTotalHistory> Search(int subscribeId, string fromDate, string toDate)
    {
        var result = FindAll()
            .Include(i => i.Subscribe)
            .Include(i => i.SubscribeTariffHistory)
            .Include(i => i.SubscribeTariffHistory.BillingCalculateType)
            .Where(
                i =>
                (i.SubscribeId == subscribeId)
                &&
                (i.Status == AnnounceState.Valid)
                &&
                (
                    (i.FromDateTime.CompareTo(toDate) <= 0
                     && i.ToDateTime.CompareTo(fromDate) >= 0
                    )
                    ||
                    (
                        i.FromDateTime.CompareTo(fromDate) <= 0
                        &&
                        i.ToDateTime.CompareTo(toDate) >= 0
                    )
                )
            );
        return result;

    }
```

But I like the fact that I need to fetch the code below

```
SELECT 
FirstCngDate = ( CASE 
        When BCT.Code = 4712
        Then
            ( SELECT
                    TOP 1 STarH.FromDateTime 
                FROM billing.SubscribeTariffHistory AS STarH 
                WHERE ( STarH.SubscribeId = STH.SubscribeId ) 
                ORDER BY STarH.FromDateTime DESC 
            )
        ELSE
            null         
      End
    )
,   
*
FROM billing.SubscribeTotalHistory AS STH
LEFT JOIN billing.Subscribe AS S ON ( STH.SubscribeId = S.Id )
LEFT JOIN billing.SubscribeTariffHistory AS STarH ON ( STarH.id =     STH.SubscribeGenralHistoryId )
    LEFT JOIN billing.BillingCalculateType AS BCT ON ( STarH.BillingCalculateTypeId = BCT.Id )
WHERE 
STH.ToDateTime = '9999/99/99' AND STH.Status = 1
```

And what I need is that I can map FirstCngDate  in subscribe.FirstCngDate ?

How to write LINQ that my output is similar to the above T/SQL.

However, I need my Out put map to `SubscribeTotalHistory` and i can use that like this

```
SubscribeTotalHistory.Subscribe.FirstCngDate
```

And I Don't Want Select New {} In My Linq. i Want Use My Domain.

Comment: You can only do that if you make `FirstCngDate` a computed column in the database.